# How to update a datagridview when changing the DataTable object reference? (C# MYSQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to do a three layer program in C# with mysql database.

I have my main form, with an datagridview inside it, and I'm loading the data of the dgv in the form load:

```
private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // load data
     C_Cliente.GetClientes();
     dgv_Clientes.DataSource = C_Cliente.dtClientes;
}
```

in my controller clientes (`C_Cliente`) class I have like this:

```
public static DataTable dtClientes;

public static void GetClientes()
{
    DAO_Cliente db = new DAO_Cliente();
    dtClientes = db.GetClientes();
}

public bool cadastrarCliente(M_Cliente cliente)
{
    // validate cliente attributes and then:
    DAO_Cliente db = new DAO_Cliente();
    if (db.CadastrarCliente(cliente))
    {
        GetClientes();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }            
}
```

and in my DAO object (`DAO_Cliente`) I have like this:

```
public bool CadastrarCliente(M_Cliente cliente)
{
    // my method to insert a client inside the mysql database, irrelevant here.
}

public DataTable GetClientes()
{
    DAO dao = DAO.getInstance(); // it just has the openconnection and closeconnection methods.
    try
    {
        dao.OpenConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = dao.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from clientes";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        dao.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Basically, when I insert a new client into my database, it calls the method `GetClientes()` which changes the `dtClientes` to a new pointer, but then, my datagridview is still using the old pointer (so it doesn't get updated). How can I fix that? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are adding new ones via the DGV, you ought not have to build a new DataAdapter or DataTable.

Comment: DataTable has a method called AcceptChanges.  For the changes to work the DataCommand needs four commands : Select, Insert, Update, Delete.  So a Command Builder will take the Select command and automatically build the other three.  See : http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/c%23/id/4922

Comment: I'm changing the database, and then I want to fire up an event that reload the datatable.

What I did: in my controller, I've cleared the original datatable and merged the new one into the older, so it get updated without changing the pointer.
https://pastebin.com/g5nmgbC0
after the insert, I just call GetClientes()
is it the right way?